# Why react function is called but the element has a negative Zindex

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have question why when I click on Grid not on the box which is {-5} the function is called but Grid is higher than the box so function should be ingored. How can I solve that.

```
   <Box zIndex={-5} onClick={hideFormModal}>
                <Grid
                  width="60vw"
                  placeItems="center"
                  position="fixed"
                  zIndex={1000}
                  top="50%"
                  left="50%"
                  transform="translate(-50%, -50%)"
                  textAlign="right"
                >
                  <motion.div
                    variants={animation}
                    initial="initialPosition"
                    animate="onShow"
                    exit="onShowExit"
                  >
                    <form onSubmit={onCommentAdd}>
                      <Grid>
                        <Input
                          placeholder="Title"
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            onCommentChangeHandler(e, setCommentTitle)
                          }
                          bgColor="white"
                          borderEndRadius="0"
                        />
                        <Textarea
                         
                          }
                         
                        />
                        <Button type="submit" borderRadius="0">
                          Add
                        </Button>
                      </Grid>
                    </form>
                  </motion.div>
                </Grid>
              </Box>
            )}
```

Comment: You should stop event propagation.

Comment: But you should also never use `zIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

z-index property will work as you expect if both elements are siblings.

Here `Box` receives `onClick` events due to event propagation.
Events are propagated from the bottom to the top of the tree.
You should add `onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}` on your grid item to stop event propagation.

For further information about this check:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#example_5_event_propagation